# Can I actually delete an element from an array at run time?

Tags: c, arrays

I want to write a simple program that delete an element from an array as per the user choice, I shift the element after the chosen one to its place, and so on. Then display an array of the (size-1), and I saw this online a lot. I want to know if I can display the array with its actual size, not size-1, and so that after the deletion there it'll still clear that one element was there but it's not any more. So if it was of size 10, after the deletion I'll still print 10 elements but last place will be empty as I deleted one element before the printing process.

Comment: Memory doesn't contain special 'garbage' data when its not being used. We just refer to uninitialized memory as 'garbage' because it will contain whatever was in that memory when it was being used last: a usually nonsense value.

Comment: why would you ever do this?

Comment: You mean you want it to go back to the same random information it had prior to the delete? And are you talking about a dynamically allocated array, or a static array? What's the use case for this, or are you just curious?

Comment: Do you mean you want to allocate a new array (if dynamically allocated) with all values except deleted one? If you want to be sure memory is cleaned (deleted value isn't visible in unallocated memory even with a raw dump/memory inspection) you have to overwrite it before you free old array. Are you trying to do this for security reasons?

Comment: I want to write a simple program that delete an element from an array as per the user choice, I shift the element after the chosen one to its place, and so on.. And then display an array of the (size-1), and I saw this online a lot. I want to know if I can display the array with its actual size, not size-1, and so that after the deletion there it'll still clear that one element was there but it's not anymore. So if it was of size 10, after the deletion I'll still print 10 elements but last place will be empty as I deleted one element before the printing process

Comment: fill the last element with some thing like -1 (note this should not appear any ware in the array). and print the list till -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, an array is just a block of memory that you are free to do with as you please.

If you want to delete an element from the end of the array, you just need to record that the array is one element shorter either by moving the null terminator or by updating some other independent length variable.

To delete an element from the front or middle you will need to move all the subsequent elements one space closer to the front.

There is no further magic involved.